# Mobile theme not using templates from theme itself in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm using **Kirigami Theme in magento 1.7**. I have installed and configured the **silver theme** for mobile devices.

After silver theme configuration, Website in mobile is coming with the style of silver theme, and catalog page is also coming from silver theme, but most of the templates or files such as search-form, product page, checkout page are not coming from silver theme, even there is a proper layout is assigned.

I made more searches with google, but I could not find why? Can help anyone on this?

Comment: can you see checkout, catalogsearch, catalog template directories in your silver theme?

Comment: I checked. All directories are there.